# how does google spread sheets detect cell clicks without changing focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-sheets

I'm working on my own web based spread sheet. I have it detecting formula and other cell references. The next step that I'd like to do is...

While I have the function bar active (in focus), if my first character is an equal sign, and I click on another cell, I'd like to be able to detect that cell then come back to the formula bar and insert that cell position.

The problem I'm having is figuring out how to track the movement from the formula bar to the cell without the cell gaining focus. I won't have an issue with the rest of it. I'm doing the bulk of this in JavaScript and using a fair chunk jQuery. I just haven't figured out which events to track on this yet.

As for examples, the site I'm working on is locked down for development, but making a Google spread sheet or even using Excel, you should see the example I'm talking about.

The formula bar is a text input, and all of the cells are in a table and are text inputs.

Comment: So this does bring me to another situation that I hadn't thought about. I need a broader way to track the clicks, such as where I am and where I came from. If for example I'm in the formula bar and I click a cell, and the formula bar is writing a function (char At 0 is '='), then I want to get the cell I clicked and append it to the formula bar. But I also need a way to click off the formula bar so I can work from additional cells. Why does google have to make it all look so easy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the "mousedown" event and prevent immediate propagation. This should prevent the focus from occurring allowing you to reference the text input but not send focus to it.

```
$(".cell input[type=text]").mousedown(function(event){

    if($("#formulaBar").val()[0] == "+"){

        event.stopImmediatePropagation();

        var cell = $(this).parent();
        var row = cell.attr("data-row");
        var col = cell.attr("data-column");

        //Do something with the formula bar
    }

});
```

I am assuming the HTML markup is as such:

```
<td data-row="0" data-column="0">
    <input type="text" />
</td>
```

Comment: that answers half of it, how would I detect that I came from the formula bar in this case? I haven't seen the .stopImmediatePropagation() function so I'm checking that out now too.

Answer (score 0):

Hi This is a sample on How you can do it, using focusOut and by and focus, if the formula text box start with "=" then you can add Cell coordinates and return the focus to your formula textbox, if you click on Enter the formula is finished and you can save it or what ever else.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <input type="text" id="txtFormular" style="width:100%"/>
    <br />
    <input type="text"  id="txtCell1" Coord="A1"  style="width:50px"/>
    <input type="text"  id="txtCell2" Coord="A2" style="width:50px"/> 
    <input type="text"  id="txtCell3" Coord="A3" style="width:50px"/>
    <input type="text"  id="txtCell4" Coord="A4" style="width:50px"/>
    <input type="text"  id="txtCell5" Coord="A5" style="width:50px"/>
    <input type="text"  id="txtCell6" Coord="A6" style="width:50px"/>
    <input type="text"  id="txtCell7" Coord="A7" style="width:50px"/>
    <script>
    $(function(){
        var formulaOn = false;
        $("#txtFormular").focusout(function(){
        if(this.value.indexOf("=") == 0)
        formulaOn = true
        else
        formulaOn = false;
        });
        $('#txtFormular').keypress(function (e) {
          if (e.which == 13) {
            //Save you formula
            this.value = "";
            this.blur();
          }
        });
        $("input[id^='txtCell']").focus(function(){
            if(formulaOn)
            {
                var txtFormulaVal = $("#txtFormular").val();
                $("#txtFormular").val(txtFormulaVal +$(this).attr("Coord"));
                $("#txtFormular").focus();
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: This looks like it'll do it. Thanks!